Keycloak Authorization with other system's account
I'm creating public API for other system can get data from my system.
so, to authenticate I uses Keycloak server.
Ex:
My system has an account tonystack, pw: 123456  (Actually, 100000 accounts)
But this account is not exist in Keycloak's user
enter image description here
How to authenticate this account by Keycloak ?
Or How to map this account with Keycloak's user account ?
(Sorry, My english is not good for explaining)
